# Socket service in Android 8

Tags: android, sockets, service

I have a problem with my app - I have a socket that needs to be running in a background service to enable user to receive chat messages while app is in background. But since Android 8.0 and its [changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html) the system will kill any service running in background after app goes to background.

I don't see any way of running a socket except running it in a foreground service, that means a notification will be shown. Considering user has 3-4 installed apps with chat capabilities (and socket running in a background service) 3-4 notifications will always be visible just to run those services. Is this the future for all the Chat applications (WhatsApp, Messenger, etc.), or is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: You need to use Push Messages: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: We would really like to stick with Socket implementation. Rewriting everything to FCM because of this restriction would take a long time.

Comment: I think using sockets is a really bad idea, especially for battery life. Imagine if every app would create it's own channel for updates from the server. Push messages really is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @PeterBruins we will consider using FCM in the future. Meanwhile any other suggestions?